# Yahoo OHLC data reflects nonexistant stock split

Tags: yahoo, split

Can anyone explain why the OHLC data I'm getting from yahoo appears to reflect stock splits during times when no significant corporate actions have occurred?

For example, I'm looking at ABT and yahoo shows a closing price jump between **Dec 31 2012** and **Jan 1 2013**.

> 2012-12-31T00:00:00.000-08:00 65.5
>   2013-01-02T00:00:00.000-08:00 32.05

But between **Oct 2012** and **Mar 2013** (according to yahoo) these are the only corporate actions that occurred

> DIVIDEND, 20130111,0.140000
>   DIVIDEND, 20121011,0.244700
>   STARTDATE, 20121001
>   ENDDATE, 20130301

What caused this price jump?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They split the company into two: ABT and ABBV. http://www.forbes.com/sites/brucejapsen/2012/10/17/a-less-acquisitive-abbott-labs-will-split-in-two-come-january/